# why can i not make my game object move with this code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hi i'd like to ask if anyone can help me fix this code and what the problem is, im brand new to coding and was just following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCBqgREiSUE)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playercontrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Vector3 v3force;
    [SerializeField]
    KeyCode KeyPositive;
    [SerializeField]
    KeyCode KeyNegative;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyPositive))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += v3force;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyNegative))
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity -= v3force;
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Get any errors? Is your script attached to a GameObject in your scene at all? Do you have any values configured via he Inspector for `v3force`, `KeyPositive` and `KeyNegative`?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code works fine on my end.
Make sure you have a Rigidbody component added to the object you want to move.
Also make sure to add a force and set your keys in the inspector.